# How to create random address from dogecoin?

Tags: wallet, address, dogecoin

It's about dogecoin. I want to make a random address everytime my customer want to give me some donation. It's just like i have multiple address that point to my main address wallet, how to that?

For example my main address is
Drpwpskxxxxxxxxx

And evertytime my members want to give donation they have different address to pay but the coin will come to my main wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Each address is an individual address. You can have multiple addresses in one wallet, but you cannot have multiple addresses pointing to the same key.

Whatever wallet system you are using should have an option to generate new addresses, either as part of an HD wallet or as individual keys. You should be able to use that to generate new addresses as required.

Remember to backup the wallet each time you generate an address if it is not an HD wallet, or remember to backup your seed words if it is.

Comment: https://github.com/coinables/Simple-Barebone-Bitcoin-Paywall, i tried to follow this tutorial. But i couldn't find my xPub for my dogecoin wallet, i'm using coinomi wallet